# How do I load an MP4 file with Blender 2.74 under Fedora?

Tags: video

I tried to repeat [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DpIXqAepfxY), loading my own MP4 file. After clicking "open" in the movie clip editor and picking the file, it didn't seem to load and here's what I got in the terminal:

```
not an anim: /path/to/file.mp4
```

At the same time, `file` says it's `ISO Media, MP4 Base Media v1 [IS0 14496-12:2003]`. Is there any preprocessing I should do before I import it to Blender? How could I do it with `mencoder` or `ffmpeg`?

Comment: I converted the file to OGV and the same thing happened. Also tried .AVI and the PoliceFootage.mov from here: http://www.videocopilot.net/tutorials/stabilize_shaky_footage/ ("project file" on the right) - nothing worked.

Comment: How can I keep tabs on / track this thread?

Comment: You can mark it as "favorite".

Comment: @NeverGiveIn: (see above)

Comment: Try downloading official blender, I assume blender is compiled without ffmpeg.

Comment: What utility did you use to convert to OGV?  Can you convert the video file to a sequence of images?

Comment: @dedwarmo: I guess I used ffmpeg, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you can convert the video file to a sequence of JPEG images Blender may have an easier time loading that.

Comment: Somehow related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47166/how-can-i-enable-mp4-h264-as-an-output-option-in-fedora-linux

Comment: Try useing a diffrent codec, it seems simple but it migt just work.

Comment: Any updates? Try adding it as a strip in the NLA, first.

Comment: The issue is not on blender, and there is nothing to set up here. Fedora (and other flavors of linux) restricts a lot of codecs by default, and the use of ffmpeg. Try using installing a blender version not from the repositories but downloaded directly from blender.org.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [build](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos) a version of ffmpeg with full support for proprietary codec.

Answer (score -1):

.mp4 is the video and audio container. Many different formats can be used inside the container.

Use VLC to open the file. Tools -  Media information (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>i</kbd>) - codec to see what the video and audio are encoded as.

You can also use VLC and Convert/Save and re-encode the video and audio in new format that can be opened by blender.

E.g. did this just now starting with mov*.mod files which contained mpeg 1/2 video and ac3 audio. Chose profile *Video - H.264 + MP3 (MP4)* Converted to .mp4 containing H264 mpeg4 avc video and mpeg audio (with same resolution video 720x576 25frames/s audio changed from 48kHz to 44kHz 32bit audio). Blender opened that format.

Answer (score -2):

In the movie clip editor, hit `SHIFT + A` and choose clip. Then, when the file browser opens, choose your mp4.

Comment: I'm sure he tried that , it's more likely the video has a corrupt header or encoded in a format ffmpeg is not built with. besides your shortcut should be Alt+O , Shift+A works in the Video Sequence editor. I didn't down-vote you btw :p