# "No valid formats found" creating a video

Tags: video

I am using blender 2.76 on openSuse.

I have created individual frames in png format and I try to create a video from frames.

Any output different from "AVI jpeg" will show a "No valid formats found" error when clicking on "Animation" to create the video. I would like to compress the video somehow and "AVI jpeg" creates huge files.

For instance, I read in Blender Stack Exchange: As of Blender 2.76 you can correctly select Output as "H.264" and Encoding as Format: MPEG-4 and Codec: H.264. This generates the correct container and encoding AFAIK

For some reason in my case this will show "No valid formats found".

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/47166/2843

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: The comment of Samoth leads me to the solution. I downloaded 2.77 buildbot version of blender here: https://builder.blender.org/download/ And use it to build my video. It just works. Thanks a lot.