# Missing FFMpeg Codecs for rendering

Tags: rendering

I'm using Blender 2.79b on Fedora 28. When I go to render a scene I only have three options for direct video output. (AVI raw, AVI Jpeg, frame server). I have checked and re-checked I have ffmpeg installed with all codecs, I also have OGG lib's installed, neither of which show up. Any help getting Blender to detect other codecs would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Joe

[image: Current codec options]

Comment: have you tried creating a new blender file and checking the video output there? If it isn't I would assume there is something wrong with your blender. If it is there, well, copy and paste it over? Good luck with your project

Comment: Check if you have ffmpeg installed on your system if not install it and that should provide you with more export options..

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Yes I tried a completely new file with the same results. I have also checked and re-checked and even reinstalled ffmpeg (a few times :). I guess I will try un-installing and re-installing blender. I will post the results here. Thank you again for your support.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load an MP4 file with Blender 2.74 under Fedora?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30885/how-do-i-load-an-mp4-file-with-blender-2-74-under-fedora)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!!! The Blender software provided by the Fedora repositories has an issue. After removing and re-installing the issue was still there. I then removed Blender via DNF and installed the package from the blender website and the issue is resolved. I now have ffmpeg and other codecs to render with. Thank you again for your support everyone. Joe

Comment: I should also add that I tested this one two different machine with the same results. I highly recommend installing directly from the package at blender.org if you are using Fedora.

Comment: It's a reported legal issue, see here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1384180 TL;DR: "Blender requires ffmpeg which cannot be legally included in the Fedora repository."